# CoreBluetooth: scanForPeripheralsWithServices not working with service array

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing a BLE application for IOS (SWIFT) and I've found a strange behaviour.. my test has 2 controllers, ONE with the CentralManager Role and the other with the PeripheralManager Role..

Here's my code (summary):

**Parameters.swift:**

```
...
// a custome UUID created in console
let TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "FB694B90-F49E-....-....-171BBA78F846")
...
```

**Peripheral.swift**

```
...
var pManager = CBPeripheralManager()
var transferService = CBMutableService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    if(peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn) {
        transferService = CBMutableService(type: TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID, primary: true)
        // add some characteristic
        pManager.addService(transferService)
        pManager.startAdvertising(nil)
    }
}
...
```

**Central.swift**

```
...
var cManager = CBCentralManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        cManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID], options: nil)
    }
}
...
```

Now, if I take 2 device, one with the Central and the other with the Peripheral Role the 2 app can't find each other (**but LightBlue app and similar will** so the device is emitting)

On the other hand, if I change the code to:

```
cManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
```

my application works perfectly and the 2 devices can communicate each other.. but at the same time I can't filter only the devices that are emitting TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID.. I don't want to connect to all peripheral finded in order to search for TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID.. isn't this the right way to proceed ?? Did I miss something ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only limited space in the Bluetooth advertisement area, so iOS does not automatically advertise all services - A device may have a primary service and several supplementary services.  Advertising all services is wasteful when all that is required is to discover the primary service in order to identify a candidate device.

To be able to discover the service in `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` you need to include the service in the advertisement data.

This is done by including the service's UUID in the dictionary you pass to `CBPeripheralManager.startAdvertising` -

```
pManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]])
```

Comment: It Works!!! You made my day! :-) Thank you very much for the explanation! I have another question.. when I've added TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID to the advertisement data, the service UUID has "lost" all characteristic and has become unusable for my work (nor Lightblue nor my application see the service anymore in "DidDiscoverServices").. is normal ?? I've solved using 2 different UUID, one for the "identification" part, in the advertisement data.. and one for the "hard work transfer service" as before.. but is the correct way ? Thx Again!

Comment: No, that doesn't sound right.  My app is in Obj-C but it advertises and I can read the characteristics with LightBlue

Comment: Ok thanks, then I'll investigate more! Thanks Again!